# How can I avoid querying the same data twice when I require 2 http responses (one a file, one a json object)?

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following layout.  If the `Export to Excel` checkbox is not checked, upon the button being pressed an API call will be made to query the data in the date range, and displayed in d3 graphs below.  If it is checked, the button makes the same API call, in addition to referencing a 2nd call that downloads an Excel file.  I *think* these 2 separate calls are necessary because I need the data in both forms (json and an attachment) which both require separate headers.  I wasn't able to figure out a way to make just one call and return the data both ways, but if that's possible I would be open to that solution.  Otherwise, what are my options to query the data just once, and share it between both calls?

[image]

Comment: A simple solution would be to cache the results of the query for a short time, since it seems the result would only change every 24 hours from the picture.

Comment: All in all, I assume the server-side query is taking a long time, since you wouldn't be optimizing this otherwise. Web application performance is a pretty broad subject. Even if narrowed down to caching (with stuff like memcache and redis).

Answer (score 0):

A HTTP request can only respond with one response type. So with a single request you can only return `json` or `excel` (whatever encoding you used). When you click that button and the excel checkbox is checked, do you need both responses? Or just the file?

If you just want the file, then ignore the JSON and do not update your d3 graphs.

If you want the graphs and the file, you'll have to make two requests, one for the JSON and one for the file. If you want to only process that DB call once on the server, you'd need something else. Like, return the JSON data and store the file at a link you'll know the address to. Or return the file and push the JSON to the client (WebSocket or similar).

If you can cache on the server (caching DB like redis or in-memory if you can guarantee you'll hit the same server node), you could store/hash the query parameters with the returned data. Any future call would check that cache first and maybe not hit the DB. (Of course, be aware that if any data would update the results, you'll need to kill your cache key so the data *is* requeried).